# ZoneID of the zone to which the wp is being added

Tags: web-part-zone, splimitedwebpartmanager

How do I find out the zoneID of the zone where my custom webpart is being added?
Have tried few things including this one.

```
AnotherWP.ZoneID = ((WebPart) mgr.WebParts["ControllerID"]).Zone.ID;
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to get the ID of the zone in which your WebPart has been added? Or do you want to add the webpart to a specific zone? Or do you want to get a collection of all ZoneID's on the current page in order to do a check so you can add your WebPart?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that mg is a SPLimitedWebPartManager:

```
string zoneId = mgr.GetZoneID(mgr.WebParts["ControllerID"])
```

Will get the ZoneID of a WebPart that is already inserted into the page.

To insert a web part into a specific Web Part Zone:

```
mgr.AddWebPart(AnotherWP, targetZoneId, 1);
```

Comment: Nope, that returns null as well, as the webpart is not yet added to the zone.

Comment: Hahahah yeah, it needs to be in a Zone to get the zone that way!

Comment: in this code: string zoneId = mgr.GetZoneID(mgr.WebParts["ControllerID"]) What is exactly ControllerID?